# Count distinct items based on group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the number of distinct items based on each id in another column.

For example

```
Color     Value
 Red       1
 Red       1
 Red       2
 Red       2
 Blue      3
 Blue      3
```

I want the count to show that Red has 2 distinct values and Blue only has 1. 
And get rid of the rows that have the higher of those distinct values when the distinct count is greater than 1. In this case I would want to get rid of the rows that say Red for color and 2 for value.

```
Color     Value
 Red       1
 Red       1
 Blue      3
 Blue      3
```

Here is my real query: In this case FormSectionID would be the color and myrank would be the value. Is there a way to use this as a subquery and get what I want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TFormSectionID AS FormSectionID, 
   TFSSortOrder AS SectionSortOrder, 
   TSectionItemID AS SectionItemID, 
   TrendType,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TFSSortOrder) AS myrank
FROM Report.TrendData
WHERE (ProgramID = 9) AND (TrendType > 0)
```

Real Data

```
FormSectionID   SectionSortOrder    SectionItemID   TrendType   Rank
12                 7                  90            1             1
12                 7                  91            1             1
12                 7                  154           1             1
12                 7                  528           1             1
12                 9                  154           1             2
12                 9                  528           1             2
```

Comment: why there are 2 rows of Blue in your expected result ?

Comment: Because the distinct count wouldnt be greater than 1 for the values of blue. The values for blue only contains 3.

Comment: @Squirrel I think he just wants to filter off any value for a color group which is not the minimum value in that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a clever `INNER JOIN` with a subquery:

```
SELECT c1.Color, c1.Value
FROM colors c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Color, MIN(VALUE) AS minValue
    FROM colors
    GROUP BY Color
) c2
    ON c1.Color = c2.Color AND c1.VALUE = c2.minValue
```

Comment: For the c1.Value, it is actually an alias in my case. It is saying invalid column name, do you know a way around this issue

Comment: You made the mistake of not showing us your real data.  Please update your question.

Comment: Just replace `Color` and `Value` with the appropriate column names.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
declare @tbColor as table (color nvarchar(5),value int)

insert into @tbColor select 'Red','1'
insert into @tbColor select 'Red','1'
insert into @tbColor select 'Red','2'
insert into @tbColor select 'Red','2'
insert into @tbColor select 'Red','3'
insert into @tbColor select 'Blue','3'
insert into @tbColor select 'Blue','3'
insert into @tbColor select 'Blue','4'

select color,value,count(*) as distinctValue from @tbcolor group by color,value
```